# Form is invalid but no errors

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views, django-crispy-forms

Whenever I submit the form, it is invalid and there is no error message attached to it when I try to read it with form.errors; it's empty. Here is what I have:

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

forms.py

```
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import FormActions
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Row, Column, Submit, Field


class SelectProjectForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, active_choices, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['is_active'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=active_choices, widget=forms.Select)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Column(Field('is_active'))
            ),
            Row(
                Column(FormActions(Submit('activate', 'Activate Project')))
            ),
        )
```

views.py

```
class ProjectSettings(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'Home/project_settings.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        active_choices = []
        for project in Project.objects.all():
            active_choices.append((project.id, project.project),)

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': SelectProjectForm(active_choices)})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'activate' in request.POST:
            form = SelectProjectForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                ....

            messages.error(request, 'Something went wrong')
            return redirect('project_settings')
```

project_settings.html:

```
<div>
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    {% crispy form %}
</div>
```

I think the problem might be in the POST method in views where I initialize the form, but I don't know how to pass the `active_choices` parameter in post. If that is not the problem then I am lost.

Comment: Show us the page template that renders the form.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated the post.

Comment: In `post()`, I don't see where the form is rendered...

Comment: There is `form = SelectProjectForm(request.POST)` in the second line of post method.

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't there be a `render()` call somewhere?  I haven't worked with crispy forms.

Comment: No, that's not how class-based views work. The rendering part is done in the get() function while post() method is only there for when a form is submitted using POST method inside the template that is linked to this class. The post() method here is equivalent to `if request.method == "POST"` of functions-based views.